# Flutter SocketIO client does not connect to python SocketIO server

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, socket.io, python-socketio

I have set up a Python SocketIOServer, shown below:

```
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}
})


@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)


@sio.event
def message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)
    sio.send(data=f"im echoing :{data}", to=sid)


@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

I tested it with another python socketio client and it worked, the `onConnect` handler was called and a reply was emitted.

I used [socket io dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) to connect to my python server, but I can't make it work.
The code in my flutter app:

```
@override
void initState() {
socket = IO.io('http://192.168.90.231:5000', <String, dynamic>{
  'transports': ['websocket'],
  'extraHeaders': {'foo': 'bar'} // optional
});

socket!.onConnect((data) {
  log('connected :'+ data);
});
socket!.onError((data) => log("Error: " + data));
socket!.on('event', (data) => log(data));
socket!.onDisconnect((_) => log('disconnect'));
socket!.on('message', (msg) => log("message from server: "+msg));
socket!.send(['test']);
log("listeners are set.");
```

}

What I get logged in my server is something like polling, every few seconds:

```
192.168.90.151 - - [11/Apr/2022 03:14:12] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000999
(3088) accepted ('192.168.90.151', 50132)
192.168.90.151 - - [11/Apr/2022 03:14:17] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000000
(3088) accepted ('192.168.90.151', 50136)
192.168.90.151 - - [11/Apr/2022 03:14:22] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000000
(3088) accepted ('192.168.90.151', 50138)
192.168.90.151 - - [11/Apr/2022 03:14:27] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000000
(3088) accepted ('192.168.90.151', 50140)
192.168.90.151 - - [11/Apr/2022 03:14:32] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000000
....
```

But my listeners (neither in server nor in client) are not called.

Comment: Looks like your client is using the older Engine.IO protocol version 3. Are you using an older Python server that matches this version of the protocol? Also, are you looking at the logs from the server?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my client and server socket.io library versions didn't match.

It was mentioned in the documentation but I didn't pay attention to it:

```
socket.io-client-dart   Socket.io Server
v0.9.* ~                v1.*    v2.*
v2.*                    v3.* & v4.*
```

I upgraded my client version to  `socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0` and it got fixed.